# It's possible create a street view such as google in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, 3d, google-street-view

I'd create an application that contanins the planimetry 2D of my room, later that I'd add the possibility to move within the room with the cursor or with the keyboard arrow. 
I just want to move into the room in 3D mode, obviously I'll add some 3D element such as one bed, a table ecc... So I'd want to move between all the object as if I was walking virtually.
Is possible to do that by using WPF? I would do such as google maps when you use street view function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, of course, but this isn't an on-topic question for Stack Overflow, as there is no real programming involved.

Comment: certainly it's possible,use keyboard to change your Camera's view

Comment: that is, I'd do this with keypress event on rectangle that contains my rooms : pressing left arrow I can change camera view. But what do you mean no real programming involved? How do you would do that?